# How to use non standard evaluation with dollar sign in r

Tags: r, non-standard-evaluation, standard-evaluation

**Context**

I want to use non-standard evaluation with dollar sign in R.

I want to customize a function with two parameters. `data` is the input data frame, `var` is the name of the variable in the input data frame. The return value is the value corresponding to the variable name.

I can do this with `fun1`.

```
library(dplyr)

df = data.frame(a = 1:3)

fun1 <- function(data, var){
  data %>% pull({{var}})
}

> fun1(data = df, var = a)
[1] 1 2 3
```

**Question**

Is there any way to perform the function of `fun1` with non-standard evaluation and dollar signs(`$`).

My solution is as follows (`fun2`) but it reports an error.

```
fun2 <- function(data, var){    # Can't create fun2, it will report an error.
  data${{var}}
}

fun2(data = df, var = a)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `[[` to extract after converting the unquoted to string

```
fun2 <- function(data, var){  
     var <- deparse(substitute(var))
     data[[var]]
}
```

-testing

```
> fun2(data = df, var = a)
[1] 1 2 3
```

It is better to use `[[` instead of `$`.  In case, we want to only use `$`, then `paste` the names and `eval` (not recommended)

```
fun2 <- function(data, var) {
  argslist <- as.list(match.call()[-1])
  eval(parse(text = sprintf('%s$%s', 
    deparse(argslist$data), deparse(argslist$var))))
}
> fun2(df, a)
[1] 1 2 3
```